# Can not use this inside a setInterval that is inside a promise

Tags: javascript, vue.js, promise

I am developing an application with vuejs. I want to use this inside a promise, I want to be able to call a function or data inside the .then scope, and for that I use the this. But if I do this inside the .then I get an error, it seems this to be lost even though I bind the scope with and arrow function. What can I do?

```
javascript
  methods: {
    ...mapActions(['setCredentials']),
    doLogin() {
      console.log('credentials ' + this.username, this.password);
      this.$store.dispatch('connect', {
        username: this.username,
        password: this.password,
      });

      this.checkResult().then((interval) =>  {
        vm.$f7router.navigate('/favorites');

      })

},
    checkResult() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {

        var id = setInterval( () => {
                let condition = this.$store.state.isConnected
                   if (condition) {
                    clearInterval(id);
                    resolve(id);
                }

            setTimeout(() => {
                clearInterval(id);
                reject(id);
            }, 20000);
        }, 10);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is due to the context binding. You can use Arrow function as they have **no** `this` property of their own (They rely on their parent function's `this` property).

Change `return new Promise(function(resolve) {..`

to `return new Promise((resolve) => {..`

Answer (score 2):

Use arrow function when instanciating your promise:

```
return new Promise((resolve) => { /* ... */ });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to create a var before the promise like:
    `var self = this;`
then use **self** instead of **this** inside the promise

Comment: thanks but this time I have problem for setTimout. gives undefined erro for reject inside setTimout even if I use arrow function , use that.reject, or solely this.reject

Comment: I see I need to define reject with resolve in function signature, thanks.